# Solve $\frac {\partial^2 v}{\partial r^2}+\frac 1r \frac {\partial v}{\partial r}-\frac v{r^2} =0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

$$\frac {\partial^2 v}{\partial r^2}+\frac 1r \frac {\partial v}{\partial r}-\frac v{r^2} =0$$ i did $$\frac {1}{r}\frac {\partial }{\partial r}\bigg( r \frac {\partial v}{\partial r} \bigg) =\frac v{r^2} $$ multiply $r $ from each side and then integrate both sides wrt $r $. And then carry on from there. Is what i did correct so far because it seems very dodgy. If it is, can someone give me a solution please.

$v(r=a)=0$ and $v (r=b) = \Omega b $

Comment: The equation you come to is legitimate.  The problem is when you say "integrate both sides with respect to r".  The right side has "v" which is itself an **unknown** function of r.

Comment: The LHS is $$\frac {\partial }{\partial r}\left(\frac {\partial v}{\partial r}+\frac v{r}\right)$$ hence the solutions solve  $$r\frac {\partial v}{\partial r}+v=cr,$$ and now the LHS is $$\frac {\partial (rv)}{\partial r},$$ hence the solutions are such that $$rv=Ar^2+B,$$ for some constants $(A,B)$, that is $$v=Ar+\frac{B}r,$$ and the boundary conditions imply finally that $$v=\Omega b\frac{(r^2-a^2)b}{(b^2-a^2)r}.$$

Comment: Oh damn... The thing is that we were not taught how to solve these euler equations in all our years of undergrad so I knew nothing of it. This came in my exam today so I was thinking of something like what I did. So i know i got the question wrong but do any of u guys think i would get any marks out of 5 for what i did (i obviously did wrongly solve and use the conditions)? I did feel a bit clever to realising these chain rule tricks haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Try guessing answers of the form
$$ v = r^ \lambda$$
You'll find 
$$ r^2 v'' + r v ' -v = r^ \lambda P ( \lambda) = 0$$
if $r>0$, then $v$ is a solution if $P( \lambda) =0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Euler differential equation.  Hint: look for a fundamental set of solutions of the form $v(r) = r^p$.